# Updating azure Enterprise Application/SP notes field via powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I believe in 2020 it was mentioned the ability to update the notes field within the properties blade of an Azure Enterprise Application was not available via Powershell.

Does anyone know if/how you can do this now?

The only thing I have noticed is the following code. It does not error when I run it but it also does not update the notes field:

Update-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $objectId -Note "test notes" # Update Notes field

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,
Rich.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe in 2020 it was mentioned the ability to update the **Note**
> Field within the properties blade of an Azure Enterprise Application
> was not available via **PowerShell**.

Now we can update the **Note** Field in **Azure Enterprise Application** using [**PowerShell**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/update-azadserviceprincipal?view=azps-7.3.0)

#### Please follow the below workaround

I am using the below command to update the **Note** Field in ***Azure Enterprise Application***

> ##### Note: Use a valid Object Id

```
    Update-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $objectId -Note "test notes updated"
```

[image]

After executing Command you have to **refresh** the ***Azure portal*** and check the **Property** blade.

#### Updated Result in Property blade After Refresh the portal

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That is how I tried it and it doesn't work. I think a combo of being remote and a CA policy might be interfering here somewhere. Thank you for confirming.

Comment: Did you refresh your azure portal !?

Comment: Yes I did refresh it. I finally have this working - Update-AzADServicePrincipal -appId $applicationId -Note $NoteInfo # Update Notes field Now the pain is I have my script coded for 'get-azuread..... set-azuread.....' commands so I have to use connect-azuread AND connect-azaccount because there is no update-azureadserviceprincipal command and the update-azadserviceprincipal is a part of the other powershell module. This is a pain because of MFA etc, I have to type and click credentials several times to get everything to run smoothly. Would be nice if update-azureadserviceprincipal was added.